# How do I count the XML properties using xpath in ruby?

Tags: ruby, xpath

I have this XML:

```
<SPEECH>
  <SPEAKER>ADAM</SPEAKER>
    <LINE>Yonder comes my master, your brother.</LINE>
</SPEECH>
<SPEECH>
<SPEAKER>ORLANDO</SPEAKER>
  <LINE>Go apart, Adam, and thou shalt hear how he will</LINE>
  <LINE>shake me up.</LINE>
</SPEECH>`enter code here`
<STAGEDIR>Enter OLIVER</STAGEDIR>
<SPEECH>
  <SPEAKER>ADAM</SPEAKER>
  <LINE>Now, sir! what make you here?</LINE>
</SPEECH>
```

How do I count how many lines are when a SPEAKER with text Adam has in total?
I tried something like this:

```
@source.xpath("//SPEAKER[//*[contains(text(), 'ADAM')]]//LINE")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Ruby, but the XPath to get all `LINE` elements from `SPEAKER` named "ADAM" would be:

```
//SPEECH[SPEAKER='ADAM']/LINE
```

or if you want use `contains` instead of an exact match for `SPEAKER`:

```
//SPEECH[contains(SPEAKER, 'ADAM')]/LINE
```

Brief explanation:

- **`//SPEECH`**: find `SPEECH` elements anywhere in the document...
- **`[contains(SPEAKER, 'ADAM')]`**: ...where its child element `SPEAKER` contains text 'ADAM'
- **`/LINE`**: from such `SPEECH` elements, select child element `LINE`

**<kbd>[xpathtester demo](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/faaa26a2db944808c23fe1714532f52b)</kbd>**

A few problems in your attempted XPath:

- `//*[contains(text(), 'ADAM')]` will match any element *within the entire XML document* that contains text 'ADAM', not just within `SPEAKER` element because it starts with `/` which point to the root document. You should, at least, add `.` at the beginning
- `LINE` is not descendant of `SPEAKER`, so `//SPEAKER[...]//LINE` will not match any element in the XML above